# MySQL cascading tables

Tags: mysql

(My website is built using PHP and MySQL.)

My DB structure for users is mainly composed of 2 tables: "doctors" and "clients".

However, in order to integrate a chat system, I need to create a third table, namely 'chat_users', which combines both doctors and clients: fields of 'chat_users' table are

```
    userid (unique integer),
    username,
    type (0:client, 1:doctor),
    refid (id of the user in the associated clients or doctors table)
```

But I do not want to insert/delete/update this table manually each time a client or doctor is inserted/updated/deleted. I heard about cascading table some time ago...

What would be the best way performance-wise to do so? How can I achieve it?

Comment: Are you trying to integrate a live chat system, or more of an email type where you send the message and the person can answer it whenever they are next on?

Comment: @JustinWood it is a live chat system called "cometchat" and they require all of the website users to be in a single database, but I cannot at this point change my entire site structure only to accomodate the chat

Comment: I would look into NodeJS. You can create real time chat systems in minutes. It would be better than putting everything in your database. Unless of course you want that information saved for whatever reason. Though, you can still save all messages with NodeJS as well.

Comment: I chose their chat system because they have plugins such as whiteboard  and voice and video chat. And with third party programs, it reduces the server load substantially...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll consider this an "answer", but may I comment on your database architecture?

You will be much happier in the long run having the following tables:

```
user_account: (ua_id, ua_email, ua_username, ua_password, etc.)
doctor: (d_id, ua_id, etc.)
customer: (c_id, ua_id, etc.)
```

In other words, have your relation going the other way.  Then if you would like to be able to delete a doctor or customer by simply deleting the user_account, you can add the following relational constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `doctor`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `doctor_fk_user_account` FOREIGN KEY (`ua_id`) REFERENCES `user_account` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `customer`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `customer_fk_user_account` FOREIGN KEY (`ua_id`) REFERENCES `user_account` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about this... would require a lot of work, but if you say it is worth it...

Comment: Will I need to use JOIN in every MySQL query in order to get some data from doctors or customers tables, or are they "virtually" part of the user_account table? (e.g. can I select "experience" which is stored in "doctor" without using a JOIN when I SELECT from user_account?

Comment: You will need to use JOIN if you want user_account information as well as doctor information.  JOINS are made inexpensive by the fact that in the process of setting up your foreign key constraints, you have to have indices on the relational columns, and of course they will be unique indices on the ua_id columns in the doctor and customer tables. Of course you can store a JOIN query as a view, but unfortunately MySQL does not have indices on views, nor does it see through a view and use the underlying indices.  So when you run EXPLAIN on a VIEW query, you'll be disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an AFTER INSERT Trigger.  This would allow you to create new users.  In case if you want it to be updated on update and deleted on delete of the original record then you need those triggers as well.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `chat_users_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `doctors` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `chat_users` SET user_id= NEW.id;
    END;
```

The above would insert a record and set the value of id.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html can give you exact syntax.  Let me know if you need any specific clarifications.

Comment: Could you please give an example of how to use AFTER INSERT or AFTER UPDATE in my context?

Comment: Triggers are a really heavy handed way to enforce this kind of consistency. I'd avoid doing this unless there is literally no other way.

Comment: I agree with you @tadman I was just trying to answer the requirement, but its always better to plan the db for the least amount of triggers

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is *not exactly* an answer to your question but what about using an old fashioned view instead? This would save you from storing redundant data altogether.

```
CREATE VIEW chat_users AS
SELECT drid    uid, drid userid,  drname username, 0  FROM doctors
UNION ALL
SELECT clid+100000, clid,         clname,          1  FROM clients
```

This view will have unique `uid`s only if you don't have more than 100000 doctors in your table (otherwise choose a higher offset). The advantage of this approach would be that there is no dependent table data to maintain.

Comment: Note that the disadvantage of a VIEW that has a lot of records is that MySQL (as of version 5.5) won't use any indices in SELECTing from the VIEW.  You can verify this by writing a SELECT query on a VIEW and then prefixing it with EXPLAIN and analyzing the output to see how many rows MySQL looked at to find your desired rows.  If this number is much higher than the number of rows you are pulling, you have a potential performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

"I do not want to insert/delete/update this table manually each time a client or doctor is inserted/updated/deleted."

Why are you fretting about this? Just do it. You have application requirements that mandate it, so unless you can figure out how to unify your client and doctor tables, you *will* need a third that relates to your chat function.

The difficulty of adding this in an application framework is almost zero, it's just the case of creating an additional record when a client or doctor is created, and removing it when their respective record is deleted.

The other answers here propose using views or triggers to obscure what's really happening. This is generally a bad idea, it means your application isn't in charge of its own data, basically handing over control of certain application logic functions to the database itself.

The best solution is often the most obvious, as that leads to fewer surprises in the future.